# Magento 2 , After the override model file give an error

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalogsearch, override-model

I override block file `Form.php`of catalog search module all work fine, but when override model file `Advanced.php` give an error from `Form.php` `Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Module\Block\Advanced\Form`. 
My code

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Advanced\Form" />
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Advanced" />
</config>
```

`Form.php`

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Advanced;

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb as DbCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

/**
 * Advanced search form
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Form extends Template
{

    protected $_categoryHelper;
    /**
     * Currency factory
     *
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $_currencyFactory;

    /**
     * Catalog search advanced
     *
     * @var Advanced
     */
    protected $_catalogSearchAdvanced;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Advanced $catalogSearchAdvanced
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        Advanced $catalogSearchAdvanced,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced = $catalogSearchAdvanced;
        $this->_currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // add Home breadcrumb
        if ($breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
            $breadcrumbs->addCrumb(
                'home',
                [
                    'label' => __('Home'),
                    'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                    'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                ]
            )->addCrumb(
                'search',
                ['label' => __('Catalog Advanced Search')]
            );
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getStoreCategories()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve collection of product searchable attributes
     *
     * @return DbCollection
     */
    public function getSearchableAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced->getAttributes();
        return $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve attribute label
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeLabel($attribute)
    {
        return $attribute->getStoreLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve attribute input validation class
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeValidationClass($attribute)
    {
        return $attribute->getFrontendClass();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search string for given field from request
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @param string|null $part
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getAttributeValue($attribute, $part = null)
    {
        $value = $this->getRequest()->getQuery($attribute->getAttributeCode());
        if ($part && $value) {
            if (isset($value[$part])) {
                $value = $value[$part];
            } else {
                $value = '';
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the list of available currencies
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAvailableCurrencies()
    {
        $currencies = $this->getData('_currencies');
        if ($currencies === null) {
            $currencies = [];
            $codes = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
            if (is_array($codes) && count($codes)) {
                $rates = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->getCurrencyRates(
                    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency(),
                    $codes
                );

                foreach ($codes as $code) {
                    if (isset($rates[$code])) {
                        $currencies[$code] = $code;
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->setData('currencies', $currencies);
        }
        return $currencies;
    }

    /**
     * Count available currencies
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCurrencyCount()
    {
        return count($this->getAvailableCurrencies());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve currency code for attribute
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function getCurrency($attribute)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve attribute input type
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getAttributeInputType($attribute)
    {
        $dataType = $attribute->getBackend()->getType();
        $inputType = $attribute->getFrontend()->getInputType();
        if ($inputType == 'select' || $inputType == 'multiselect') {
            return 'select';
        }

        if ($inputType == 'boolean') {
            return 'yesno';
        }

        if ($inputType == 'price') {
            return 'price';
        }

        if ($dataType == 'int' || $dataType == 'decimal') {
            return 'number';
        }

        if ($dataType == 'datetime') {
            return 'date';
        }

        return 'string';
    }

    /**
     * Build attribute select element html string
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeSelectElement($attribute,$attributeCode=null)
    {
        $extra = '';
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

        $name = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

        // 2 - avoid yes/no selects to be multiselects

            array_unshift($options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __($attributeCode)]);


        return $this->_getSelectBlock()->setName(
            $name
        )->setId(
            $attribute->getAttributeCode()
        )->setTitle(
            $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute)
        )->setExtraParams(
            $extra
        )->setValue(
            $this->getAttributeValue($attribute)
        )->setOptions(
            $options
        )->setClass(
            'multiselect'
        )->getHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve yes/no element html for provided attribute
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeYesNoElement($attribute)
    {
        $options = [
            ['value' => '', 'label' => __('All')],
            ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes')],
            ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')],
        ];

        $name = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        return $this->_getSelectBlock()->setName(
            $name
        )->setId(
            $attribute->getAttributeCode()
        )->setTitle(
            $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute)
        )->setExtraParams(
            ""
        )->setValue(
            $this->getAttributeValue($attribute)
        )->setOptions(
            $options
        )->getHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Get select block.
     *
     * @return BlockInterface
     */
    protected function _getSelectBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getData('_select_block');
        if ($block === null) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class);
            $this->setData('_select_block', $block);
        }
        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Get date block.
     *
     * @return BlockInterface|mixed
     */
    protected function _getDateBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getData('_date_block');
        if ($block === null) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date::class);
            $this->setData('_date_block', $block);
        }
        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search form action url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSearchPostUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/result');
    }

    /**
     * Build date element html string for attribute
     *
     * @param AbstractAttribute $attribute
     * @param string $part
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDateInput($attribute, $part = 'from')
    {
        $name = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '[' . $part . ']';
        $value = $this->getAttributeValue($attribute, $part);

        return $this->_getDateBlock()->setName(
            $name
        )->setId(
            $attribute->getAttributeCode() . ($part == 'from' ? '' : '_' . $part)
        )->setTitle(
            $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute)
        )->setValue(
            $value
        )->setImage(
            $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::calendar.png')
        )->setDateFormat(
            $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
        )->setClass(
            'input-text'
        )->getHtml();
    }
}
```

`Advanced.php`

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\OverrideAdvancedForm\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection as ProductCollection;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\AdvancedFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute as EntityAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Catalog advanced search model
 *
 * @method int getEntityTypeId()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setEntityTypeId(int $value)
 * @method int getAttributeSetId()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setAttributeSetId(int $value)
 * @method string getTypeId()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setTypeId(string $value)
 * @method string getSku()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setSku(string $value)
 * @method int getHasOptions()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setHasOptions(int $value)
 * @method int getRequiredOptions()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setRequiredOptions(int $value)
 * @method string getCreatedAt()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setCreatedAt(string $value)
 * @method string getUpdatedAt()
 * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setUpdatedAt(string $value)
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Advanced extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * User friendly search criteria list
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_searchCriterias = [];

    /**
     * Product collection
     *
     * @var ProductCollection
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies
     *
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $_catalogConfig;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Attribute collection factory
     *
     * @var AttributeCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_attributeCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Product factory
     *
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * Currency factory
     *
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $_currencyFactory;

    /**
     * Advanced Collection Factory
     *
     * @var ProductCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    private $_objectManager;
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param Config $catalogConfig
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Config $catalogConfig,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->_attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->_currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $advancedFactory->create(),
            $this->productCollectionFactory->create(),
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Add advanced search filters to product collection
     *
     * @param   array $values
     * @return  $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function addFilters($values)
    {
        $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
        $allConditions = [];

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Attribute */
            if (!isset($values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()])) {
                continue;
            }
            $value = $values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()];
            $preparedSearchValue = $this->getPreparedSearchCriteria($attribute, $value);
            if (false === $preparedSearchValue) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->addSearchCriteria($attribute, $preparedSearchValue);

            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                $rate = 1;
                $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
                $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
                if ($currency != $store->getBaseCurrencyCode()) {
                    $rate = $store->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($currency);
                }

                $value['from'] = (isset($value['from']) && is_numeric($value['from']))
                    ? (float)$value['from'] / $rate
                    : '';
                $value['to'] = (isset($value['to']) && is_numeric($value['to']))
                    ? (float)$value['to'] / $rate
                    : '';
            }

            if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'datetime') {
                $value['from'] = (isset($value['from']) && !empty($value['from']))
                    ? date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($value['from']))
                    : '';
                $value['to'] = (isset($value['to']) && !empty($value['to']))
                    ? date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($value['to']))
                    : '';
            }
            $condition = $this->_getResource()->prepareCondition(
                $attribute,
                $value,
                $this->getProductCollection()
            );
            if ($condition === false) {
                continue;
            }

            $table = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
            if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'static') {
                $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            } else {
                $attributeId = $attribute->getId();
            }
            $allConditions[$table][$attributeId] = $condition;
        }
        if ($allConditions || (isset($values['cat']) && is_numeric($values['cat'])) ) {
            $this->_registry->register('advanced_search_conditions', $allConditions);
            $this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);
        } else {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter a search term and try again.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve array of attributes used in advanced search
     *
     * @return array|\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = $this->getData('attributes');
        if ($attributes === null) {
            $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
            $attributes = $this->_attributeCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addHasOptionsFilter()
                ->addDisplayInAdvancedSearchFilter()
                ->addStoreLabel($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                ->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')
                ->load();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $attribute->setEntity($product->getResource());
            }
            $this->setData('attributes', $attributes);
        }
        return $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve advanced search product collection
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addStoreFilter();
            /* need to include product active and visibility filtering here*/
            /* include category filtering */
            if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare product collection
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSearchIds());

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add search criteria.
     *
     * @param EntityAttribute $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addSearchCriteria($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $this->_searchCriterias[] = ['name' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(), 'value' => $value];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add data about search criteria to object state
     *
     * @todo: Move this code to block
     *
     * @param   EntityAttribute $attribute
     * @param   mixed $value
     * @return  string|bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function getPreparedSearchCriteria($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (isset($value['from']) && isset($value['to'])) {
                if (!empty($value['from']) || !empty($value['to'])) {
                    if (isset($value['currency'])) {
                        /** @var $currencyModel Currency */
                        $currencyModel = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->load($value['currency']);
                        $from = $currencyModel->format($value['from'], [], false);
                        $to = $currencyModel->format($value['to'], [], false);
                    } else {
                        $currencyModel = null;
                    }

                    if (strlen($value['from']) > 0 && strlen($value['to']) > 0) {
                        // -
                        $value = sprintf(
                            '%s - %s',
                            $currencyModel ? $from : $value['from'],
                            $currencyModel ? $to : $value['to']
                        );
                    } elseif (strlen($value['from']) > 0) {
                        // and more
                        $value = __('%1 and greater', $currencyModel ? $from : $value['from']);
                    } elseif (strlen($value['to']) > 0) {
                        // to
                        $value = __('up to %1', $currencyModel ? $to : $value['to']);
                    }
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }

        if (($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select' ||
                $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') && is_array($value)
        ) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                $value[$key] = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($val);

                if (is_array($value[$key])) {
                    $value[$key] = $value[$key]['label'];
                }
            }
            $value = implode(', ', $value);
        } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select' || $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
            $value = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = $value['label'];
            }
        } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'boolean') {
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $value = $value == 1 ? __('Yes') : __('No');
            } else {
                $value = false;
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns prepared search criterias in text
     *
     * @return arrayasfcewflweo
     */
    public function getSearchCriterias()
    {
        $search = $this->_searchCriterias;
        /* display category filtering criteria */
        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) {
            $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_GET['cat']);
            $search[] = array('name'=>'cat','value'=>$category->getName());
        }
        return $search;
    }
}
```

in `Form.php` i added `getStoreCategories()` function

in `Advanced.php` i replaced

```
 public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = $this->_searchCriterias;

    return $search;
}
```

To

```
 public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = $this->_searchCriterias;
    /* display category filtering criteria */
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) {
        $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_GET['cat']);
        $search[] = array('name'=>'cat','value'=>$category->getName());
    }
    return $search;
}
```

AND

```
if ($allConditions)
```

To

```
if ($allConditions || (isset($values['cat']) && is_numeric($values['cat'])) )
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, top in `Form.php` i needed to change use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced; to use Vendor\Module\Model\Advanced;